# How to display only a drop-down list of items not previously selected

Tags: laravel

I have two tables

- tenant=>id,name,email,property_id
- property=>id,propertyname,location

The ‘tenant’ and ‘property’ table has a one to relation.

My tenant/create.blade.php has a drop-down list of all the properties in the database available for rent.

For example if in the database the following properties are inserted A,B,C,D,E,F. The drop-down list displays all properties including those already taken. As in figure

[image]

I want it to display only properties not taken. For example if out of all properties available A,B,C has previously been assigned the it should only display a drop-down list of D,E,F

I think I can do this in the controller but dont know how.

Here is my TenantsController create function

```
public function create()
    {
        $property = Property::pluck('propertyname','id');

        return view('tenants.create',compact('property'));

    }
```

The create.blade.php has the following code to display the drop-down list

```
<div class="form-group">

    {{Form::label('property name','Property Name')}}
    {{Form::text('propertyname','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Property Name'])}}
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be more solutions, but right now I can think of `$collection->diff()` to quickly solve it within your laravel app.

```
$properties = Property::all();   // write query to fit your needs
$taken      = Property::taken(); // write query to retrieve the unavailable properties

$diff    = $properties->diff($taken);
$options = $diff->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

Now, pass the `$options` to your blade view & loop through it to generate `<option>`.